# The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: Unable to resolve resource

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've searched a lot in StackOverflow and I believe that it's not duplicate.
I'm working on a ASP Razor project, when I click F12 to navigate to the references in my project this error shows.
This has happened to all my projects; I disabled all newly installed extensions but again the error exists.
I tried another PC with synced VsCode but again faced error.
does anyone knows the reason and the solution ?
Please see these pictures:
[image]

*Update : I removed **C#** and **C# Dev kit** and reinstalled them. my problem has been fixed.*

Comment: potentially useful google search in the future: [`github vscode issues "The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: Unable to resolve resource"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=github+vscode+issues+%22The+editor+could+not+be+opened+due+to+an+unexpected+error%3A+Unable+to+resolve+resource%22). Right now the search results are not that related.

Comment: I'd actually suggest that you raise an issue ticket. Use the `Help > Report Issue` feature of VS Code to create an issue ticket. If you do, please ping me with a link to your issue ticket.